# Javascript: Click a link on a page using span text as reference

Tags: javascript, html, css

Sorry if this is a dumb question but I'm very new to HTML and javascript.

I'm trying to click a button/link on web page not having a unique identifier (at least that's what I'm seeing).
Below is the snippet of the HTML Code.
Is it possible if I could reference the span value/text immediately below the 'a' element (e.g. "Search Incident", "New Incident")?

Or are there any other ways I could go about this?

```
"<div class="item EP lvl1 " navmode="1" artype="NavBarItem" arid="app1598" lvl="1" arwindowid="0" style="height: 25px; overflow: visible; border-top: medium none; border-bottom: medium none;">

    <a class="btn" style="z-index: 1;" onclick="javascript:CallARGHPD_58INC_58AppListEntryPointamrrm6100EPFunc(false, this);">

        <span class="navLabel lvl1 ">

            New Incident

        </span>
    </a>

</div>
<div class="item EP lvl1 " navmode="1" artype="NavBarItem" arid="app1599" lvl="1" arwindowid="0" style="height: 23px; overflow: visible; border-left: 1px solid rgb(…, 233); border-top: medium none; border-bottom: medium none;">

    <a class="btn" style="z-index: 1;" onclick="javascript:CallARGHPD_58INC_58AppListEntryPoint_95Searchamrrm6100EPFunc(false, this);">

                <span class="navLabel lvl1 ">

                    Search Incident

                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>"
```

**EDIT**

This is what I've done so far:

> Store the whole form into a variable by referencing the ID and filtering by tag name, as below;

```
var links = IE.Document.getElementById("WIN_0_80077").getElementsByTagName("a");
```

Basically the form is outlined like below, clicking through each like a folder structure, to access the inner link.

```
Form
  |  Incident Management
    |  New Incident (links to another page)
    |  Search Incident (links to another page)
  |  Problem Management
    |  New Problem (links to another page)
    |  Search Problem (links to another page)
```

Each has span attribute with their corresponding text as described on the outline.

> Navigate to the inner structure by clicking each button/link (e.g. Incident Mgt > Search Incident)
>    - Im trying to achieve this by looping on the links using span text as reference (or any viable reference)

```
for (link in links) {
    for (span in link.getElementsByTagName("span")) {
        if (condition) //validation for span text {
            span.click;
        }
    }
}
```

Does this even make sense at all? Again, sorry if it did not. Appreciate you help.

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the suggestions.
It might not be the best solution but at the least, I was able to make a way out by implementing below.

```
// Reference the intended element/class/item
var link = objIE.Document.querySelectorAll('a[onclick="javascript:CallARGHPD_58INC_58AppListEntryPoint_95Searchamrrm6100EPFunc(false, this);"]');

// Do something with it (e.g. click the link)
link[0].click();
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. What are you trying to achieve, what have you tried, and what effect are you seeing? This would be why people are voting down your question

Answer (score 0):

You could do this a number of ways in JavaScript but one way would be to reference the span elements by class using

```
var labels = document.querySelectorAll('.navLabel');
```

This will return all the elements with the class 'navLabel'

Then to reference the individual label, you could do:

```
var firstLabel = label[0].innerHTML;
var secondLabel = label[1].innerHTML;
```

Again, there are multiple ways to do this, it just depends what you want to do with the references after you get them.

Comment: thanks! I was able to get something to work using your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
var label=document.getElementByClassName('navLabel lvl1');

label[0].value;     //New Incident
label[1].value;     //Search Incident
```